# Get segments of a polygon divided by lines

Tags: javascript, python, geometry, polygon

I'm looking for a way to **find all segments of a polygon that is divided** by lines between some of its points.

Here are two examples to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So my data and desired output looks like this:

**Example A:**

```
Outline: [P1, P2, P3, P4]
Divisions: [P1, P3]

Expected Result: 
  Segment A [P1, P2, P3]
  Segment B [P1, P3, P4]
```

**Example B:**

```
Outline: [P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7]
Divisions: [P1, P3] and [P1, P6] and [P3, P6]

Expected Result:
  Segment A [P1, P2, P3]
  Segment B [P1, P3, P6]
  Segment C [P1, P6, P7]
  Segment D [P3, P4, P5, P6]
```

Please note that there will never be any crossing lines.

**Question**: What kind of algorithm would return the desired output? I'm using JS/Typescript, but Python, pseudocode or any other language or even just an idea would highly be appreciated!

Comment: How are the divisions picked? For `A`, why wasn't `[P2, P4]` chosen? For `B`, why not `[P3, P7]` or `[P1, P5]`?

Comment: @MattDMo That is the input data I'm working with - they were picked by a user.

Comment: Kinda echoing @MattDMo's question, it's not clear what the criteria is for dividing the polygon into segments.  Eg, B has segments made up of triangles and a four point near-square polygon.  Given that, why can't A simply be a four point polygon rather than being divided into triangles?